# How to filter the same list 2 times with 2 different filter input. (FIlter by SearchView and Tag)

Tags: java, android, filter, tags

I am currently doing an Android Studio app that recommends activities to people.

In short, I want to filter a list, and then filter the already filtered list again.

I am intending for the ListView display of activities to be searched/filtered by the location of the activity.
I also want to have a tag system that filters the activities according to tags such as #Solo #Family #Food.

Currently I implemented both system, however they overlap each other.

After I filter the list with location, if I try to filter the filtered list with tag system, the list resets and is no longer filtered by location, and only by the tags. Is there a way to filter the list by location first, then filter the already filtered list by tags?

Thanks for your help :)

Code for filter by location

```
    public void filter (String charText) {
    charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
    recommendationInfoList.clear();
    if (charText.length() == 0) {
        recommendationInfoList.addAll(arrayList);
    } else {
        for (RecommendationInfo rc : arrayList) {
            if (rc.getLocation().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText)) {
                recommendationInfoList.add(rc);
            }
        }
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

---

```
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.mainSearchView);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            if (TextUtils.isEmpty(newText)) {
                adaptor.filter("");
                mListView.clearTextFilter();
            } else {
                adaptor.filter(newText);
            }

            return true;
        }
    });
```

And code for filter by tag

```
public void tagFilter (String charText) {
charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
    recommendationInfoList.clear();
    if (charText.length() == 0) {
        recommendationInfoList.addAll(arrayList);
    } else {
        for (RecommendationInfo rc : arrayList) {
            if (rc.getTags().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText)) {
                recommendationInfoList.add(rc);
            }
        }
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

---

```
    TextView tagFilter = findViewById(R.id.filterByTags);
    tagFilter.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            System.out.println("Text ["+s+"]");

            adaptor.tagFilter(s.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                                      int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });
```

[Picture of the "error" -> the filter by location gets replaced by filter by tag, instead of filtering the already filtered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XdADf.png)

Comment: Please post your code so we could get more of the context

Comment: I have added in my code. Was unable to do it when posting so I had to edit it in :) Thank you so much!

Comment: Make a new list with first filteration and then use the filter method again for the next filteration. Or you can add an and condition.

Comment: yeah agree, you need to filter with 2 input keys at the same time